# Can I host a ASP.NET (4.6.1) App on a Linux server?

Tags: asp.net, mono, kestrel-http-server

I recently tested an ASP.NET Core app on my Linux Server hosted via Mono & Kestrel. Everything worked well, however, I had to change from ASP.NET Core due to some unsupported packages that were essential for the app.

I am new to ASP.NET so not 100% sure what I am doing incorrectly, but now when I try to dotnet run/dotnet build my server says:-

DOTNET1011: Framework not installed: .NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1

Is there anything I can do as a work around? I understand Core was designed to be multi-platform but with so many unsupported pacakage's it wasn't fit for purpose.

Thanks

Comment: You have to switch to pure .NET Core in your project.json file. And also note Mono is irrelevant here.

Comment: Sorry, yeah as I mentioned the only 3 packages/libraries that I need to work are not supporting .NET Core. Is there no way around this?

Comment: No there is no way round this.